# Laravel 6 : Duplicate database entry on polymorphisme relation save

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-6.2

I try to save a morph relationship in my database, but when i try to save it I Have tow entry in every table use for the relation.

here is my client class

```php
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function clientelle(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

my particulier class

```php
class Particulier extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function client(){
        return $this->morphOne(Client::class,'clientelle');
    }
}
```

So when I try to save like that :

```php
$particulier = new Particulier();
$particulier->nom = $request->nom;
$particulier->prenom = $request->prenom;
$particulier->save();

$particulier->client()->create(['telephone'=>$request->telephone,'adresse'=>$request->adresse,'email'=>$request->email]);
```

My database save two same recorde. Here is my problem.

So I have try diffrente thing to avoid it but I have error every time

- delete `$particulier->save();` but SQL error id don't exist
- replace create([...]) by save([...]) or sync([...]) but don't work

Thank you in advance

Comment: Missing I'd from database

Comment: No that generated 2 id but same info in the tow id

Comment: use associate method. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships

Comment: I have find the solution but it's realy worst
So when i send a post request this request is send to time.
To correct this I have create attribute on my controler and I verify if my attribute as be incremented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have finally find a worst solution...

In your controller add int var and init it to 0 like that :

```php
Private $checkDouble=0;
```

In place where you want save your relation create if block and put in all of your model save like that :

```php
if($this->checkDouble==0) {
   $this->checkDouble = $this->checkDouble + 1; //Increase your var value 

   $particulier = Particulier::create(['nom' => $request->nom, 'prenom' => $request->prenom]);
   $particulier->client()->create(['telephone' => $request->telephone, 'adresse' => $request->adresse, 'email' => $request->email]);
}
```

And no more duplicate data

I know is really worst solution but I don't see any best solution ^^